# Combining two rewrite rules leads to infinite loop

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I`d like to combine the following Cond/Rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.[^.]+)(\.(uk|ar|cy|ar|tr))?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

the first one prefixes all requests without www. subdomain with www. and the second one should should change all http requests to https.

The result is an infinite loop. How can I combine thoses two?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the webserver operates behind a proxy. So we have to do the https check differently. This works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```